# Combinig 2 form fields to do a range search

Tags: javascript, forms

I have been trying to find a method of combining 2 form fields to create a 3rd hidden field for submitting as a numeric range search. I have found numerous examples of combining text fields using javascript but have not been able to make them work, I would be very grateful for any advice as to where I am going wrong or if there is a simple way of doing this.

what I have so far is below

in the head section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function combprice() {
    var lowprice = document.forms[0].lowprice.value;
    var highprice = document.forms[0].highprice.value;
    document.forms[0].price.value = lowprice + " " + highprice;
  }
</script>
```

then the form

```
<FORM ACTION="cgi-bin/sales.cgi" METHOD="POST" name="search" id="search"><table width="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr>
    <td width="91"  height="30"><div align="right">Make <span class="style4">:</span> </div></td>
    <td width="129">

      <div align="left">
        <input name="Make" type="text" size="13" />
      </div></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td  height="30"><div align="right">Model  </div></td>
    <td>

      <div align="left">
        <input name="Model" type=text size="13" />
      </div></td></tr>

  <tr>
    <td  height="30"><div align="right">Min Price <span class="style4">:</span> </div></td>
    <td>

      <div align="left">
        <input id="lowprice" name="lowprice" type="text" size="13" maxlength="13" />
      </div></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td  height="30"><div align="right">Max Price <span class="style4">:</span> </div></td>
    <td>

      <div align="left">
        <input id="highprice" name="highprice" type="text" size="13" maxlength="13" />
      </div></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><table width="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td  height="30"><div align="right">Price:</div></td>
        <td><input name="Price" type="text" id="Price" size="13" maxlength="13"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90"  height="30">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="130"><div align="center"><input name="Submit" type="submit" id="OnSubmit" value="Search" onclick="combprice()">

        </div></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

none of the fields are required fields.

I am aware that the above does not include the <= or => elements, I just have not managed to get that far. 
Thanks in advance

```
                Leo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a case mismatch between `name="Price"` and `document.forms[0].price`

Works fine when they match

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/egvbm/)**</kbd>